# Count reoccurring elements in multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a number of names divided into several lists. I am printing all the names which occur in more than one list, sorted by the number of occurrences.

What is a better/easier/more pythonic way of doing this? I feel like my solution is overly complicated.

```
import numpy as np


list_1 = ['John Cleese', 'Terry Gilliam']
list_2 = ['Eric Idle', 'Terry Jones', 'Michael Palin']
list_3 = ['Graham Chapman', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave', 'Terry Jones']
list_4 = ['Arthur, King of the Britons', 'Terry Jones', 'John Cleese']
list_5 = ['Michael Palin', 'Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-as-Sir-Lancelot']

all = sorted(np.unique(list_1+list_2+list_3+list_4+list_5))


def in_how_many(name):
    result = 0
    if name in list_1:
        result += 1
    if name in list_2:
        result += 1
    if name in list_3:
        result += 1
    if name in list_4:
        result += 1
    if name in list_5:
        result += 1

    return result


names_list = []

for name in all:
    if in_how_many(name) > 1:
        name_dict = {'name': name, 'value': in_how_many(name)}
        names_list.append(name_dict)

for person in sorted(names_list, key=lambda k: k['value'], reverse=True):
    print '\'%s\' is in %s lists' % (person['name'], person['value'])
```

This prints:

```
'Terry Jones' is in 3 lists
'John Cleese' is in 2 lists
'Michael Palin' is in 2 lists
```

Comment: Your examples are very Pythonic ;-)

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and the [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

A naive implementation could be:

```
import collections

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]
counter = collection.Counter(sum(lists))

for name, amount in counter.most_common():
    print('\'%s\' is in %s lists' % (name, amount))
```

This however will mean if `list_1` is `['a'] * 5` it will say `'a'` is in five lists when this isn't true. A dictionary comprehension is all that's needed for this building a dictionary from the lists, setting the value to 1. And you can take advantage of the fact `collection.Counter` has addition defined.

```
counter = sum(
    collection.Counter({name: 1 for name in names})
    for names in lists
)
```

---

Without using `collections.Counter` I would advise you use `set`. Firstly it removes the need for using `np.unique` and emphasis the fact that `sorted` is redundant, as sets are unordered.

It also means that making `all` is simple and reduces `name in list_1` from an \$O(n)\$ operation to an \$O(1)\$ operation. Leading to faster code.

As shown earlier it's easier to work with lists, rather than a list of variable names and so `lists` is defined the same as above.

```
sets = [set(names) for names in lists]
all = sum(sets)


def in_how_many(value, sets):
    return sum(
        value in set_
        for set_ in sets
    )
```

---

No matter which of the above two solutions you use you still have a couple of other problems:

- Don't put code in global scope, have a `main` function. This makes it harder to do bad things or mess up.
- You should use `if __name__ == '__main__'` to only allow the code in `main` to run if it's the 'main' file.
- In relation to the above two, notice that I pass `sets` to `in_how_many`. This is because you shouldn't rely on global scope as it makes reusing the same code harder to do.
- Modulo formatting was deprecated for a while, because it's generally worse than `str.format` and is more susceptible to errors. I suggest using `str.format` or upgrading to Python 3.7 to take advantage of f-strings.
- Import `print_function` form `__future__` to make `print` a function. This makes it easier to upgrade to Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import collections
import functools
import operator


def main(lists):
    counter = functools.reduce(
        operator.add,
        (
            collections.Counter(set(names))
            for names in lists
        )
    )

    for name, amount in counter.most_common():
        print('{name!r} is in {amount} lists'.format(name=name, amount=amount))
        # print(f'{name!r} is in {amount} lists')  # Python 3.7 f-string.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(...)
```

Comment: Your second code block does not work at all. `sum` of values which do not have addition with `0` defined need a zero-element supplied as second argument to `sum`. Using an empty `collections.Counter` (mind typo in your code) would work, but the rest still doesn't.

Comment: @Graipher You are correct, that it doesn't work. But this is because `sum` isn't the same as `reduce(add, ...)`. It seems to be something like `reduce(add, [0] + ...)`.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But even when fixing that, I could not get it to work...

Comment: @Graipher Ah, I missed an `s` above. I've verified that the above works in 2.7.16.

Answer (score 2):

This exercise can be solved using the tools in the Python standard library, namely the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module and the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

- First, you want to ensure that just because a name appears twice in the same list, it is not double-counted. Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) for that (or a comprehension).
- Then you want to parse all names from all lists, use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for that.
- Finally you need to count how often each name appeared, which you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for (just like in the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220390/98493) by [@Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz)).

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]

no_of_lists_per_name = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(set, lists)))

for name, no_of_lists in no_of_lists_per_name.most_common():
    if no_of_lists == 1:
        break # since it is ordered by count, once we get this low we are done
    print(f"'{name}' is in {no_of_lists} lists")
# 'Terry Jones' is in 3 lists
# 'John Cleese' is in 2 lists
# 'Michael Palin' is in 2 lists
```

If you are learning Python now, don't learn Python 2, unless you *really* have to. [It will become unsupported in less than a year](https://pythonclock.org/). And Python 3(.6+) has nice [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which make formatting a lot easier (I used them in the code above).

Note that you can mix string quotation marks. I.e. if you need single-quotes `'` inside your string, use double-quotes `""` to make the string (and vice-versa). This way you don't need to escape them.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Because I started with OP's code and did not think of it. Afterwards I saw it in your answer but decided to leave it, so both alternatives are there.